# Implement sticky articles in Drupal views?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a Drupal 7 view with articles sorted by date.

I want the option to make any articles sticky ie top of the list via publishing options and then sort by date.

How do I configure the Drupal 7 view to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple sort options in your view configuration. You would create the first sort to be by stickied items (descending), and the second to be by date. In the sort options there is a drop-down and you can select re-arrange. From here, ensure that the sticky sort is first in the list.

Comment: Glad it worked! You can mark this as an answer as per: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers